# How to send user specific notification via Web push

Tags: javascript, json

I'm implementing web push on chrome and everything works well except that I don't know how to get user specific notification from the server. On send, everybody gets d same thing.

Is there a way I can pass endpoint ID to the latest notification request from service worker? Or how else can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that tutorial - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a data storage implemented of all subscribed clients on the server `endpoint.txt` that can be read and then message can be delivered to a specific user.

More on that part here: [developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API#The_server)

Part of the function that sends broadcast message that you can modify to pick one client not all of them in for-loop: https://github.com/chrisdavidmills/push-api-demo/blob/gh-pages/server.js

```
  if(obj.statusType === 'chatMsg') {
        fs.readFile("endpoint.txt", function (err, buffer) {
          var string = buffer.toString();
          var array = string.split('\n');
          for(i = 0; i < (array.length-1); i++) {
            var subscriber = array[i].split(',');
            webPush.sendNotification(subscriber[2], 200, obj.key, JSON.stringify({
              action: 'chatMsg',
              name: obj.name,
              msg: obj.msg
            }));
          };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data with a message to a user but you need to encrypt the payload data. This has been in Firefox for a while in a few versions and is in a few versions of Chrome.

Check out libraries like the following:

- https://github.com/marco-c/web-push
- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-push-encryption/
- https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push